# Unable to match a specific number with "grep -E"

Tags: command-line

Here I'm trying to search numbers ranging from 0 to 255, but some random numbers get matched instead. Examples are:

```
1335.0.1.234
```

or

```
241.92.88.103
```

Bolded are the numbers which are matched.

This number which I get has a number which exceeds 255, but is still matched because it sees 1 as a standalone number(?). Even if the number does not exceed 255, random parts of the number gets matched.

The command I'm using is:

```
grep -E '[0-255]' asd.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand regular expressions: `[0-255]` does not mean "a decimal number between `0` and `255`", but means "one of `0`, `1`, `2` or `5`".

This is the correct regular expression:

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])\b
```

If you try, you should get the following output:

```
$ grep -E '\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])\b' asd.txt
1335.0.1.234
241.92.88.103
```

(All numbers except 1335 have been matched.)

---

**Bonus tip:** If you want only the matched numbers (without the dots and the unmatched numbers), use `-o`:

```
$ grep -Eo '\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\b' asd.txt
0
1
234
241
92
88
103
```

---

**Another tip:** If you want to match valid IPv4 addresses (one per line), use the following command:

```
grep -E '^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])$' asd.txt
```

Comment: What if I want it to only search for the first 3 digits only,and then followed by and dot then using {4} to repeat it? What would I need to change?

Comment: @user3787219: you want to match valid IP addresses?

Comment: yes, I want to find valid IP addresses

Comment: @user3787219: updated answer. However note that the web is full of regular expressions for matching IP addresses :)

Comment: I actually wanted the experience as I'm very new to this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: are there any changes required when \b is replaced with ^ and $? It's either not working of I'm not doing it right

Comment: @user3787219: `\b` matches the word boundary, `^` matches the start of the line, `$` matches the end of the line. What problems are you experiencing? Perhaps, aren't your IP addresses are one per line?

Comment: if I were to closely follow yours by using 'grep -E ^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])$' asd.txt , there is a missing ')' and if I add the ), no results are returned

Comment: @user3787219: mh, I think I understood. You are using the regular expression without quoting it. You should use `grep -E "^...$"`, not `grep -E ^...$`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/BwX0oF9.png I'm sorry but I just cannot see what is wrong

Comment: @user3787219: you are using another expression. Copy and paste the one from my answer.

Comment: @user3787219: I've updated the answer to show you the exact command.

Comment: there is only one result for some reason,  http://i.imgur.com/AvvFFZu.png  http://i.imgur.com/jzOLqYe.png . there is actually more than 1 that should should be matched..

Comment: @user3787219: I tried with your file, but it works for me (`12.12.12.12` is matched, `127.0.0.0` is matched, ...). Are you sure the IPAddresses.txt file you are seeing is the same you are giving to grep?

Comment: Found the way to make it work for me, using \< and \> instead of ^ and $..